# Skip item from arraylist in Gridview while inflating android

Tags: android

I have an ArrayList of 30 items , i am inflating those items in my grid view.
I am inflating only 20 items. 
From 0-3,5-8,10-13,15-18. and leaving the rest.

How to skip elements from arraylist in gridview  while inflating

Comment: Just create one another ArrayList which holds 0-3,5-8 and so on values.. And pass it to inflate.. :)

Comment: Or just write your own `Adapter`

Comment: @ChintanRathod i do not want to do that way.is there any option to skip while inflating

Comment: @StefandeBruijn i am using custom adapter ,

Comment: you'll have to write a reroute table, indicating the 4=5, 5=6 ... 8=10, 9=11 ..., then use that in your getItem, and change the getCount to return the real number of items. (also, that's 16 items, not 20)

Comment: Um... I think `view.setVisibility(View.GONE);` will make a trick.. :P

Comment: @ChintanRathod No . does not hack any thing

Comment: Can't you change order of elements?? I tried.. but fail.. :(

Comment: @ChintanRathod i think i should go for creating a new arraylist

Comment: Hm.. you should.. Its very efficient..

Comment: @njzk2  Hi  buddy , i was trying to give a try to your comment can you please explain little more . Also that are 20 items ,i forgot to say about 20-23

Answer (score 1):

public int getCount()
{
    if(list.size() > 20)
        return 20;
    return list.size();
}